# ANGULARJS fill with empty array an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

So i have this json

```
"inventory": {
      "data": {
        "0": {
          "id": 637,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 0,
          "name": "Slot Extender (Low)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "4": {
          "id": 3247,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 4,
          "name": "Lamp of Dazzlement (Lv. 4)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "7": {
          "id": 637,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 7,
          "name": "Slot Extender (Low)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "8": {
          "id": 1454,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 8,
          "name": "Vampiric Earring +7",
          "desc": null
        },
        "11": {
          "id": 12,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 11,
          "name": "Return Stone",
          "desc": null
        },
        "12": {
          "id": 2425,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 12,
          "name": "Vital Potion (Lv. 2)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "14": {
          "id": 3094,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 14,
          "name": "Holy Water of Critical Strike (30 min)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "16": {
          "id": 3247,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 16,
          "name": "Lamp of Dazzlement (Lv. 4)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "20": {
          "id": 10,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 20,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (Medium)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "22": {
          "id": 10,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 22,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (Medium)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "23": {
          "id": 2444,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 23,
          "name": "Strike Potion (Lv. 1)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "24": {
          "id": 19,
          "upgrade": 9,
          "bind": 4,
          "slot": 24,
          "name": "Citrine Orb",
          "desc": null
        },
        "26": {
          "id": 124,
          "upgrade": 15,
          "bind": 1,
          "slot": 26,
          "name": "Aramid Battlesuit",
          "desc": null
        },
        "28": {
          "id": 2704,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 28,
          "name": "Weapon Option Scroll (High)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "29": {
          "id": 214,
          "upgrade": 15,
          "bind": 4,
          "slot": 29,
          "name": "Aramid Battleboots",
          "desc": null
        },
        "44": {
          "id": 169,
          "upgrade": 13,
          "bind": 4,
          "slot": 44,
          "name": "Aramid Battlegloves",
          "desc": null
        },
        "47": {
          "id": 663,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 47,
          "name": "Force Regen. Potion (Lv. 1)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "48": {
          "id": 1,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 48,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (High)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "56": {
          "id": 2342,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 56,
          "name": "Holy Water of Fighter",
          "desc": null
        },
        "59": {
          "id": 2381,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 59,
          "name": "Enchant Safeguard (Highest)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "64": {
          "id": 2338,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 64,
          "name": "Holy Water of Vitality",
          "desc": null
        },
        "65": {
          "id": 1116,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 65,
          "name": "Snow Ice MP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "66": {
          "id": 5,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 66,
          "name": "HP Potion (Lv. 3)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "68": {
          "id": 1381,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 68,
          "name": "Copper Coin",
          "desc": null
        },
        "72": {
          "id": 320,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 72,
          "name": "Life Absorb Ring +2",
          "desc": null
        },
        "74": {
          "id": 582,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 74,
          "name": "Force Core (Low)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "75": {
          "id": 2,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 75,
          "name": "Force Core (High)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "76": {
          "id": 2339,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 76,
          "name": "Holy Water of Speed",
          "desc": null
        },
        "80": {
          "id": 3278,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 80,
          "name": "Skill Book (Split Specialty Stage 3)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "82": {
          "id": 3276,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 82,
          "name": "Skill Book (Sword Splitter)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "84": {
          "id": 3277,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 84,
          "name": "Skill Book (Split Specialty Stage 2)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "86": {
          "id": 34,
          "upgrade": 5,
          "bind": 1,
          "slot": 86,
          "name": "Citrine Crystal",
          "desc": null
        },
        "96": {
          "id": 3293,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 96,
          "name": "Minesta Training Book Chapter 15",
          "desc": null
        },
        "105": {
          "id": 1214,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 105,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (Highest)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "106": {
          "id": 1214,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 106,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (Highest)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "107": {
          "id": 1214,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 107,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (Highest)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "128": {
          "id": 1116,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 128,
          "name": "Snow Ice MP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "129": {
          "id": 2345,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 129,
          "name": "Holy Water of Flawless Defense",
          "desc": null
        },
        "130": {
          "id": 1116,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 130,
          "name": "Snow Ice MP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "131": {
          "id": 1115,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 131,
          "name": "Snow Star HP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "132": {
          "id": 1115,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 132,
          "name": "Snow Star HP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "133": {
          "id": 1115,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 133,
          "name": "Snow Star HP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "134": {
          "id": 1116,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 134,
          "name": "Snow Ice MP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "142": {
          "id": 2,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 142,
          "name": "Force Core (High)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "196": {
          "id": 1275,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 196,
          "name": "Periodical Remote shop card",
          "desc": null
        }
      }
```

This is a json object of some items into some character's inventory. The key is basically the item slot ID in that inventory.
What i want is to fill with empty arrays based on missing keys in AngularJS. For example if you take the first 2 items, first has 0 key and the second one has key 4 so there are missing 1,2,3 and i want to fill with empty arrays with those missing keys. And i want this process to repeat till the maximum of 255 arrays!
Can anyone nicely please help me with a code or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
for( var i=0;i<255;i++){
    if(inventory.data[i] == undefined){
        inventory.data[i] = {};
    }
}
```

I assume that you want to assign empty object to non existing keys.

Answer (score 0):

One other way of doing this would be like ;

```js
var data = {
        "0": {
          "id": 637,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 0,
          "name": "Slot Extender (Low)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "4": {
          "id": 3247,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 4,
          "name": "Lamp of Dazzlement (Lv. 4)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "7": {
          "id": 637,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 7,
          "name": "Slot Extender (Low)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "8": {
          "id": 1454,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 8,
          "name": "Vampiric Earring +7",
          "desc": null
        },
        "11": {
          "id": 12,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 11,
          "name": "Return Stone",
          "desc": null
        },
        "12": {
          "id": 2425,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 12,
          "name": "Vital Potion (Lv. 2)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "14": {
          "id": 3094,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 14,
          "name": "Holy Water of Critical Strike (30 min)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "16": {
          "id": 3247,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 16,
          "name": "Lamp of Dazzlement (Lv. 4)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "20": {
          "id": 10,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 20,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (Medium)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "22": {
          "id": 10,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 22,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (Medium)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "23": {
          "id": 2444,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 23,
          "name": "Strike Potion (Lv. 1)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "24": {
          "id": 19,
          "upgrade": 9,
          "bind": 4,
          "slot": 24,
          "name": "Citrine Orb",
          "desc": null
        },
        "26": {
          "id": 124,
          "upgrade": 15,
          "bind": 1,
          "slot": 26,
          "name": "Aramid Battlesuit",
          "desc": null
        },
        "28": {
          "id": 2704,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 28,
          "name": "Weapon Option Scroll (High)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "29": {
          "id": 214,
          "upgrade": 15,
          "bind": 4,
          "slot": 29,
          "name": "Aramid Battleboots",
          "desc": null
        },
        "44": {
          "id": 169,
          "upgrade": 13,
          "bind": 4,
          "slot": 44,
          "name": "Aramid Battlegloves",
          "desc": null
        },
        "47": {
          "id": 663,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 47,
          "name": "Force Regen. Potion (Lv. 1)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "48": {
          "id": 1,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 48,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (High)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "56": {
          "id": 2342,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 56,
          "name": "Holy Water of Fighter",
          "desc": null
        },
        "59": {
          "id": 2381,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 59,
          "name": "Enchant Safeguard (Highest)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "64": {
          "id": 2338,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 64,
          "name": "Holy Water of Vitality",
          "desc": null
        },
        "65": {
          "id": 1116,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 65,
          "name": "Snow Ice MP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "66": {
          "id": 5,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 66,
          "name": "HP Potion (Lv. 3)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "68": {
          "id": 1381,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 68,
          "name": "Copper Coin",
          "desc": null
        },
        "72": {
          "id": 320,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 72,
          "name": "Life Absorb Ring +2",
          "desc": null
        },
        "74": {
          "id": 582,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 74,
          "name": "Force Core (Low)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "75": {
          "id": 2,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 75,
          "name": "Force Core (High)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "76": {
          "id": 2339,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 76,
          "name": "Holy Water of Speed",
          "desc": null
        },
        "80": {
          "id": 3278,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 80,
          "name": "Skill Book (Split Specialty Stage 3)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "82": {
          "id": 3276,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 82,
          "name": "Skill Book (Sword Splitter)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "84": {
          "id": 3277,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 84,
          "name": "Skill Book (Split Specialty Stage 2)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "86": {
          "id": 34,
          "upgrade": 5,
          "bind": 1,
          "slot": 86,
          "name": "Citrine Crystal",
          "desc": null
        },
        "96": {
          "id": 3293,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 96,
          "name": "Minesta Training Book Chapter 15",
          "desc": null
        },
        "105": {
          "id": 1214,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 105,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (Highest)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "106": {
          "id": 1214,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 106,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (Highest)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "107": {
          "id": 1214,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 107,
          "name": "Upgrade Core (Highest)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "128": {
          "id": 1116,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 128,
          "name": "Snow Ice MP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "129": {
          "id": 2345,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 129,
          "name": "Holy Water of Flawless Defense",
          "desc": null
        },
        "130": {
          "id": 1116,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 130,
          "name": "Snow Ice MP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "131": {
          "id": 1115,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 131,
          "name": "Snow Star HP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "132": {
          "id": 1115,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 132,
          "name": "Snow Star HP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "133": {
          "id": 1115,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 133,
          "name": "Snow Star HP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "134": {
          "id": 1116,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 134,
          "name": "Snow Ice MP Potion",
          "desc": null
        },
        "142": {
          "id": 2,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 142,
          "name": "Force Core (High)",
          "desc": null
        },
        "196": {
          "id": 1275,
          "upgrade": 0,
          "bind": 0,
          "slot": 196,
          "name": "Periodical Remote shop card",
          "desc": null
        }
      },
 ar = Array(255).fill().map((e,i) => data[i] || {}); // all in array
console.log(ar);
obj = Array(255).fill().reduce((p,c,i) => (p[i] = data[i] || {},p),{});  // all in object
console.log(obj);
```